# WIX Custom Action is not Executing during Upgrade

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am unable to execute custom action during Upgrade.It is giving the following error in logs.

Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: CA_DFADMINWSPUPGRADE, location: E:\DealFoundrySetUp\, command: "E:\DealFoundrySetUp\PSScripts\UpdateAminWSP.bat" "Admin.wsp" "E:\DealFoundrySetUp\DFAdmin\AdminWsp\Admin.wsp" 
MSI (s) (74:B4) [17:03:11:416]: Product: DealFoundry -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: CA_DFADMINWSPUPGRADE, location: E:\DealFoundrySetUp\, command: "E:\DealFoundrySetUp\PSScripts\UpdateAminWSP.bat" "Admin.wsp" "E:\DealFoundrySetUp\DFAdmin\AdminWsp\Admin.wsp"

```
 <CustomAction Id="CA_DFADMINWSPUPGRADE" Impersonate="no"
                    ExeCommand='"[INSTALLDIR_UG]PSScripts\UpdateAminWSP.bat" "[PRO_ADMINWSPNAME_UG]" "[PRO_ADMINWSPPATH_UG]"'
                    Directory="INSTALLDIR" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
```

INSTALLDIR_UG value i am saving in Registry and during installation and using while Upgrade

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR_UG">
      <RegistrySearch Id="rsDFInstallDirectory"
                      Name="DFInstallDirectory"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\VALUEMOMENTUM\DEALFOUNDRY\DealFoundryAdmin"
                      Type="raw"
                      Win64="yes">
      </RegistrySearch>



</InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="CA_DFADMINWSPUPGRADE" After="InstallFiles">
            <![CDATA[INSTALL_DFUSERMANAGEMENT=1 AND (OLDER_VERSION_FOUND)]]>
          </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Any one help me plz.

Comment: What's the E: drive? If it's a mapped drive it will not work for an impersonate="no" custom action.

Comment: it is not mapped Drive its INSTALLDIR location.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to `Impersonate="yes"` i think your script might not execute as Local System.